# Issue reinstalling macOS Mojave after failed Ubuntu installation

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, mojave, install, unix

I have a MacBook Pro 15 on which I tried to install Ubuntu 20.04 as my host OS. However, the installation has failed. Whilst waiting for the Linux forums to help me out with the installation, I am trying to go back to macOS, but I am unable to do so.

[image: Photo of a Unbuntu error dialog box]

Next, I entered Recovery Mode (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>), then selected "Reinstall macOS". However, when the software asks me to select a drive, I found no drives at all. So, I can not continue and complete the installation.

[image: Photo of Recovery Mode with no drives listed]

I also tried to restore the main drive from Disk Utility, but received the following error:

[image: Photo of Disk Utility failing to restore from the disk image]

Can somebody please help me reinstall macOS on the MacBook Pro 15?

Comment: Do you have a backup of your data? If so, you might consider reformatting an nvme partition to APFS using disk utility and installing mojave there. I recently dual-booted mine with mojave and linux, and to do this I created fresh partitions from disk utility on a blank drive from recovery mode, then installed macos, then installed linux.

Comment: Post the output of `diskutil list` from Terminal in Recovery. i can't see enough of the left column in your second pic to try figure out what you've done.

Answer (score -2):

You've probably corrupted your hard drive while installing ubuntu and messed up the info, so you need to get a new hard drive and replace it, or
if you have a backup drive and backup computer install macOS Mojave on it, set it as the main boot, and don't remove it.

You can also take it to a repair store to get it fixed, or buy a new mac.

If none work (mainly because you can't buy anything, you're low on money, or have nothing other than the mac), you're screwed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).